# Why can't i detect this file?

Tags: linux, grep

I have this file in a directory say test.php whose contents are below

```
< ? php $XZKsyG=’as’;
```

I want to pick up the file test.php with a search based on its content. So  from the directory containing it I do:

```
grep 'php \$[a-zA-Z]*=.as.;'
```

However I get no result...what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the clarification:  do you want to match the pattern against filenames, file contents, or something else?

Comment: Regardless of whether you're searching one file or multiple files, the answer to why you weren't finding the result you expected to is the same. So I'd suggest going back to the original version of your question. (To search within a directory use `grep -r 'pattern' .`, and you can find many other questions about that on [Super User](http://superuser.com))

Answer (score 1):

That works fine for me, though you may want to look into those "funny" single quotes you have around `as`:

```
pax$ cat testfile
< ? php $XZKsyG='as';

pax$ grep 'php \$[a-zA-Z]*=.as.;' testfile
< ? php $XZKsyG='as';
```

Failing that, there's some things you can look at. Some of these may sound silly but I'm really just checking all bases.

- Are you sure the file contains only what you think it does? Executing `od -xcb file` will give you a hex dump of it for better checking.
- Are you sure you're accessing the right file, in the right directory?
- Have you done something silly like aliasing `grep` to be something else?

---

That's if you're looking for a file containing that string. If instead you're looking for a file *named* like that, you can use something like:

```
ls -1 | grep 'php \$[a-zA-Z]*=.as.;'
```

The `ls -1` command gives you one file per line, and piping that through `grep` will filter out those not matching the pattern.

I suppose I should mention that I'm not really a big fan of file names with spaces in them, but I'm *violently* opposed to file names made up of PHP scripts :-)

Comment: i am actually looking for a file containing text within it that matches that pattern...:(

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
$ cat file
< ? php $XZKsyG=’as’;
$ grep 'php \$[a-zA-Z]*=.as.;' file
< ? php $XZKsyG=’as’;
```

Are you sure the contents of the file are exactly what you showed us?

Try `cat -A file` or `od -c file` to see whether the file really looks the way you think it does.

(Note that you don't need to escape the `$` character; it's only a metacharacter at the end of a line.  But escaping it should be ok.)

**EDIT :**

The characters around the `as` in your file are not ASCII apostrophes; they're Unicode RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK characters (0x2019).  If the file is stored in UTF-8, each of them is represented as a 3-byte sequence.  The `grep` command works for me because my locale settings `"en_US.UTF-8"` are such that a UTF-8 character is matched by `.` in a regexp, even if it has a multi-byte representation.  I suspect your locale is such that it would be matched by `...`.

Probably the simplest solution is to edit the file to use ASCII apostrophes.

You might also want to play around with your locale settings.  Try the `grep` command with `$LANG` set to `"en_US.UTF-8"`.

What's the output of the `locale` command?

Comment: Oops! Im sorry I am trying to search the directory for a file containing that pattern not search a file for the pattern...how do i modify the command?

Comment: Try something like `grep -l <pattern> *` or `grep -r -l <pattern> .` to search subdirectories.  But of course first you have to get the search pattern right.